# Enabling render type for Mapzen Global Terrain in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, dem, color-ramp

I'm trying to change the color ramp on a Mapzen Global Terrain layer and only 'Singleband color data' is available in render type. 'Singleband pseudocolor' is not available. This is occurring in QGIS 3.16 and 3.32, on Windows.

Any ideas why? Am I missing something?

(Or another simple way to represent a global dem with a color ramp?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS 3.32

- Open the Layer -> Data Source Manager menu.
- Select XYZ
- Select Mapzen Global Terrain
- Ensure "URL" is set to "https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/terrarium/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
- Ensure "Interpretation" is set to "Terrarium Terrain RGB"

[image]

[image]